# Method Security With @PreAuthorize - RequestHeader Does Not Refresh After 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I've developed a method that is annotated with @PreAuthorize.  The @PreAuthorize annonation runs a method (called isStringInList(String s)) on a separate class (a @Service that I've qualified as "myStringEvaluationService") to ensure that the method returns true.

Eg:

```
@PreAuthorize("@myStringEvaluationService.isStringInList(#myString)")
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndPoint", method = POST)
void executeThisMethodIfAuthorised(@RequestHeader(name = "whateverTheStringIs") String myString) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm using Postman to send HTTP requests to the method.  If I send a String that is on the list the above method executes fine.  If I send a String that isn't on the list then the method doesn't execute - this is fine, it's how I want it to behave.  It sends a 403 - Forbidden message back to Postman.

The problem is when I resubmit a String that is on the list, I see from debugging that the String that is not on the list is what gets sent for every subsequent request.  For some reason the 403 error doesn't result in the myString variable being refreshed.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

I had written a Security Configuration class that extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and overrode that class' configure(HttpSecurity http) method.  Initially I had merely included some code to permit any requests mapping onto the endpoint.  What was happening that was causing the problem was that when I submitted a String in the HTTP header that wasn't on the list, Spring Security was caching the URL.  Even though I changed the header of subsequent requests, I wasn't changing the URL and Spring Security considered that URL to be in violation of security and hence blocked the request.

The remedy for this was to include the following two lines of code in the configure(HttpSecurity http) method

```
http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
http.requestCache().disable();
```

By disabling the request cache the new header was read every time a request was sent.